# How to avoid replicating callback functions (C++)

Tags: c++, c++11, callback, function-pointers

I am using an API which only accepts void callback functions:

> void (* CALLBACKFUNC) (void);

I want to call the callback function with parameters, instead of writing multiple callback functions with the same functionality for different input parameters. 
Let's say I need a callback function like

> void myFunc (int a);

**UPDATE**: more information: calling the callback function, based on the events should be like:

> event1 -> calling myFunc(1); 
>   event2 -> calling myFunc(2); 
>   ...

***The number of events is limited*** and a MAX is predefiend (if it helps), but I do not want to replicate the functionality (actually, in the real case, there are multiple input values, and replicating the function call for the different combinations is not an easy job)

**P.S:** I can use C++11 as well. Any suggestions?.

Comment: What have you tried? Please show us some (relevant) code. And if you have errors, please show them as well.

Comment: I tried to pass a functor instead of the function pointer, which obviousely I got the error: cannot convert argument x from 'FUNCTOR_TYPE' to 'CALLBACKFUNC'

Comment: You can use `std::function` and `std::bind` for customized callback functions. These are C++11 features.

Comment: Are you designing the API or are figuring out the best way to integrate with a pre-existing API?

Comment: @TOWI_Parallelism: If you can't change the API, then you can't have stateful callbacks.  However, you _can_ have stateless callbacks which all use shared functionality, which might be enough for your case.

Comment: In c++98, you do not have option of functor. You have to work with function pointers. In that case workaround will be `void (*callback)(void*)` .

Comment: No, I am not designing the API. I am just using it. But my application needs non-void callback functions.

Answer (score 4):

What about this solution? You don't need to define manually new function to set different states.

```
#include <iostream>

void setState(int s) {

    std::cout << "Set state to " << s << std::endl;

}

template <int n>
void myWrapper() {
    setState(n);
}


void myLogic(void(*CALLBACK)(void)) {

    CALLBACK();
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {


    myLogic(myWrapper<50>);
    myLogic(myWrapper<100>);

}
```

Comment: Alright, I accepted this solution, but I didn't know that "Non-type Template Arguments" should be known at compile-time. I don't see how this could be useful. I mean, if cannot pass an argument to the wrapper, it is not gonna help. right?

Comment: @TOWI_Parallelism: that is true, so unaccept it, so the question is seen by other ppl as not answered. I will think about it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to pass a `void (* CALLBACKFUNC) (void)` and this can't be changed, then you cannot pass stateful functions, period.  However, you can share functionality:

```
void myFunc (int a) {
   std::cout << a;
}
void myFunc1() {myFunc(1);}
void myFunc2() {myFunc(2);}
void myFunc3() {myFunc(3);}
void myFunc4() {myFunc(4);}
void myFunc5() {myFunc(5);}

int main() {
    use_callback(myFunc1);
    use_callback(myFunc2);
    use_callback(myFunc3);
    use_callback(myFunc4);
    use_callback(myFunc5);
}
```

If this doesn't work for you, then you need to redesign your code, and/or use globals to pass state around.  If you *absolutely must*, and I *do NOT recommend this*, you can use an array of callbacks and give each their own global state.

```
 struct callback_state {
     int p;
 };
 struct callback_meta {
     bool is_used = false;
     CALLBACKFUNC func;
     callback_state state {};
 };
 static const size_t max_callbacks = 6;
 callback_meta meta_array[max_callbacks];
 lock_type global_callback_lock; //of course you'll need a lock
 #define GLUE2(X,Y) X##Y
 #define GLUE(X,Y) GLUE2(X,Y)
 #define DEFINE_CALLBACK(X) void GLUE(func,X) { \
         real_func(meta_array[X].state.p); \
         globcal_callback_lock.lock(); \
         meta_array[i].is_used = false; \
         globcal_callback_lock.unlock(); \
     } \
     meta_array[X].func = GLUE(func,X);

 CALLBACKFUNC prepare_callback(callback_state state) {
     CALLBACKFUNC ret = 0;
     globcal_callback_lock.lock();
     for(int i=0; i<max_callbacks; ++i) {
         if(meta_array[i].is_used == false) {
             meta_array[i].state = state;
             meta_array[i].is_used = true;
             ret = meta_array[i].func;
             break;
         }
     }
     globcal_callback_lock.unlock();         
     return ret;
 }
 DEFINE_CALLBACK(0); //boost preprocessor would go a long way here
 DEFINE_CALLBACK(1);
 DEFINE_CALLBACK(2);
 DEFINE_CALLBACK(3);
 DEFINE_CALLBACK(4);
 DEFINE_CALLBACK(5);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mooing Duck! I m actually amazed by your speed of thinking and coding! I can only accept one answe thoug! I think I have to go for the Krab's answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is one solution, but it is more like a hack and it is not 
platform independent. It will work only on 32bit x86 architecture
when cdecl calling convention is used.

```
#include <iostream>

const int PARAMS = 0xCAFEBABE; // set this value to be something unique (read below)

typedef void(*CALLBACK)(void);

void functionICantModify(CALLBACK cb) {

    cb();

}

/*
 * It depends on how on x86 with cdecl calling convention the stack frame
 * is generated by most compilers.
 *
 *
 * Stack frame when called as myCallback();
 *        <--- esp is now same as ebp and points to old ebp on stack (mov ebp, esp)
 * [ebp] ; this is old ebp (push ebp)
 * [returnAddress] ; return address to functionICantModify
 * [undefined] ; possibly local variable of functionICantModify or old ebp
 *
 *
 * Stack frame when called as myCallback(PARAMS, 10, 50)
 *        <--- esp is now same as ebp and points to old ebp on stack (mov ebp, esp)
 * [ebp] ; this is old ebp (push ebp)
 * [returnAddress] ; return address to function from where i called myCallback(PARAMS, ...)
 * [PARAMS] ; this is our flag
 * [param1]
 * [param2]
 *
 *
 * ebp register acts like a frame pointer.
 * When access to local variables, ebp is substracted (first local 32bit variable is [ebp-4], second [ebp-8], ...)
 * When access to function arguments, ebp is added (first 32bit argument is [ebp+8], because [ebp] points to old ebp and [ebp+4] is return address (on 32bit architecture)
 *
 * You can see from those stack frames abowe that when you will access the paramsFlag in myCallback when
 * myCallback called from functionICantModify, you will get that undefined value. So it is important
 * to set the PARAMS value to be something unique that will never appears on stack in that place when
 * myCallback is called. By checking paramsFlag, you can detect if the function is called by
 * functionICantModify or by your logic.
 */
void myCallback(int paramsFlag, int param1, int param2) {

    /*
     * This is how prolog is generated by most compilers on x86 (intel syntax)
     * push ebp
     * mov ebp, esp
     */
    static int _param1 = 0;
    static int _param2 = 0;

    if (paramsFlag == PARAMS) { // called from my logic, setup state
        std::cout << "Called to set state";
        _param1 = param1;
        _param2 = param2;
    }
    else { // called from functionICantModify, don't access the function parameters !!!!!!!!!!!!!
        std::cout << "Called from functionICantModify, _param1=" << _param1 << ", _param2=" << _param2 << std::endl;
    }

    /*
     * This is how epilog is generated by most compilers on x86 with cdecl (intel syntax)
     * mov esp, ebp
     * pop ebp
     * ret
     */
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    myCallback(PARAMS, 10, 50);
    functionICantModify((CALLBACK)myCallback);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Credit goes to *Krab* for pointing out the non-type temoplate arguments. Let's play a game with the compiler. If it does not like runtime variables, give it one at compile-time: a pointer.

```
void setState(int s) {
    printf("a is: %d\n", s);
}

template <int *n>
void myWrapperss() {
    setState(*n);
}

int a;

void myLogic(void(*CALLBACK)(void)) {
    CALLBACK();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    a = 3;
    myLogic(myWrapperss<&a>);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution :-) It has limitations of course. But these limitations should not matter much for your case where the number of events is known at compile-time. This approach allows runtime states for the callbacks.

```
#include <iostream>

template <int id>
class StatefulCallback {
public:
  typedef void Callback(); 
  static Callback* get(int v) {
    s_state_ = v;
    return callback; 
  }

private:
  static int s_state_;
  static void callback() {
    std::cout << s_state_ << '\n';
  }
};

template <int id>
int StatefulCallback<id>::s_state_ = 0;

int main() {
  const int MAX = 10;

  auto callback_for_event1 = StatefulCallback<1>::get(7);
  auto callback_for_event2 = StatefulCallback<2>::get(9);
  // ...
  auto callback_for_eventMAX = StatefulCallback<MAX>::get(3);

  callback_for_event1();
  callback_for_event2();
  // ...
  callback_for_eventMAX();
}
```